# n-th root of product of random variables (as convergence)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $U_1,U_2,...$ be a sequence of independent, identically uniformly distributed RVs on the interval $[0,1]$. Show that there is a constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $(U_1 U_2 \cdot\cdot\cdot U_n )^{\frac{1}{n}} \longrightarrow a$ 
           for $n \longrightarrow \infty$.
Here, the almost sure convergence is meant...

So, if I handle the $U_i$ as numbers between $0$ and $1$, I would suggest $X_n := (U_1 U_2 \cdot\cdot\cdot U_n )^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges a.s. towards 0, because if you multiply infinitely many of them, there surely is a $0$ among them and then $X_n$ converges to $0$. If there is no $0$ among the factors, it would converge towards $1$, if I am correct.

But I don't really know how to show it for RVs, since we haven't done any similar tasks in class, so I hope someone could show me how to prove it using the right notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(U_1U_2\cdots U_n)^{1/n} = \exp \left (\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ln(U_i) \right)
$$

$$
x = \ln(u) \to dx = 1/u\, du\to dx = e^{-x}du
$$ $x\in (-\infty,0]$ so $-\ln(U_i) \in Exp(1)$ and the average converges a.s by the law of large numbers. $e^x$ is a continuous function hence the expression converges to $e^{-1}$ a.s.

Also we can do the expectation directly as this derivation confuses some people,
$$
E[\ln(U)] = \int_0^1 \ln(x)\,dx   = \Big [ x\ln(x) - x \Big ]_0^1 = -1.
$$
Note that we used e.g. Lhopital's rule to see that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x\ln(x) = 0.
$$

Comment: I don't really see how you applied the law of large numbers.. the law of large numbers says: $\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i} X_i - \mathbb{E} \longrightarrow 0$ for $n \longrightarrow \infty$ .. but in your sum the expected value doesn't appear

Comment: $E(ln(U)) = E(-X)=-1,\,\, X\in \text{Exp}(1)$

Comment: that limit is the same as $S_n \to E(X_1)$

Comment: with $S_n$ you mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i} log(U_i)$ ? I'm sorry, I still can't follow you how I have to apply the law of large numbers :(

Comment: yes that's my $S_n$. Each infinit sequence has a probability P on it and the set $A$ of sequences that converges like normal number has $P(A) = 1$ so you can consider $a_n=S_n$ real numbers and $a=EX_1$ is a real number so hwat you have is $\lim_n a_n - a = 0$ which is $\lim_n a_n = a$ which is $lim_n S_n= EX_1$ on the set $A$. So what you do is to stay in the set $A$ and do the math.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: I believe it should instead be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \log U_i = \mathbb{E} \log U_i = -\infty$ and hence it converges to $e^{-\infty} = 0$, as the OP suspected.

Comment: You can indeed calculate $E \log(U)$ directly and that is -1 as well. I added the calculation to the answer. Thanks!